# com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to crunch file

Tags: android

Building the project throws the following
error:

> Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: 
>   Failed to crunch file ....\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed.9.png into ....\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed.9.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Error: File path too long on windows, keep below 240 characters***

Just try to use shorter path for your project. In my case i have just moved my project folder to desktop and after opening project from desktop this problem will disappear automatically.